# when i input and submit name and img url it doesn't reveal on the other page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

This the node js code
when ever i launch the server and go to /campground/new and input new name and image url then it redirect me to campground that have all the image but the one that i added doesn't show up there, please someone help me

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  var bparser = require("body-parser");

  var campgrounds = [
  {name: "peter parker", image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504591504549-8ce1589ea6f6?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e175ed478c674ed124bae4f873a3a164&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"},
        {name: "colt steele", image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517771778436-39f5763f5270?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1a13e64c2ca5f8236aebd26c4226acf2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"}, 
        {name: "matt atkinson", image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506404214625-2c59d5e6e912?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=b6eddec898e383419d38114f39a35561&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"} 

      ];

   app.use(bparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");


app.get("/campground", function(req,res){

       console.log(campgrounds);
      res.render("campground.ejs", {campgrounds: campgrounds});

});
app.post("/campground", function(req, res){

var name = req.body.name;
var image = req.body.image;
var campgroundNew = {name: name , image: image};

campgrounds.push(campgroundNew);

 console.log(campgrounds);

res.redirect("/campground");

});

app.get("/campground/new", function(req, res){

    res.render("new.ejs");
});
```

this is form new.ejs file

```
<form action="/campground" method"POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" name="image" placeholder="image"> 
    <button>Post</button>
</form>


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("The yelpCamp server has Started!!");
});
```

Comment: it supposed to do that to check if it's working but actually it doesn't print nothing it just print the object i hope you help me it's been 24 hours

Comment: nothing appears

Comment: can i share my code on cloud9

Comment: i am learning code always this make it hard for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, for each request the array `campgrounds` is initialised again, with the same elements that you have hardcoded in your code. So, for each new request it's always the same old array and hence only shows these images. Perhaps you need to save your new `img` and `name` in a session variable, or in a file or in database.